# NoClassDefFoundError in facebook integeration

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am using facebook integration API in my code. I have created `sha1` key for Facebook,I got my `APIID` ,but the problem is that when I am trying to add facebook library in my project it's adding fine ,but when I am running it, its giving me `NoClassDefFoundError`  error and library is not adding properly, where am I doing wrong?

Here is the image:

> [image]

Here my facebook library is not adding properly, What should I do ?

Comment: Have you used any external jar lib?

Comment: put your library project under same folder where you have your main project and then add this library project as you did and then try..

Comment: no sir.,i have just imported that

Comment: Okay tell me in which directory you have your main project, can you give me exact path like e:Rajshree->Newfolder like this give me your full path

Comment: C:\Users\Techvalens\Downloads\First Android

Comment: Okay then move your facebook library project from E: drive to 
C:\Users\Techvalens\Downloads\ and then add it from this path, it will definitely work.

Comment: ok sir..,i understood...

Comment: So try this and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your facebook SDK library project and your Current Android project both should be in same directory. Try moving your facebook sdk library to your project's folder then it will 100% work properly.

For future reference always remember that your library project must me in same folder where your appliction is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes and Click on Apply and clean the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir i have done this,but when i am importing librray its giving me error which i have put image snippest in my code..,

Answer (score 0):

Move your Facebook SDK library to your project's work space then it will 100% work properly.I think they both are not in the same directory , and you are suggested to check the other imports of any other project of your work space and put the Facebook SDK  same as the others.